# unable to read respone from python server

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am writing a simple python server and using do_GET to return a html by following

```
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
   def _writeheaders(self):
       self.send_response(200)
       self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
       self.end_headers()

   def do_HEAD(self):
       self._writeheaders()

   def do_GET(self):
       f = open("/full/path/to.html")
       self._writeheaders()
       self.wfile.write(f.read())


serveraddr = ('localhost', 7070)
srvr = HTTPServer(serveraddr, RequestHandler)
srvr.serve_forever()
```

in the html a have

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>myChart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<div >
    ...divs...
</div>


<script>

...js functions...

</script>

<body>

<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

I was able to get the html, however in the browser console says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` at `jquery-1.8.2.min.js:1`

If I directly open html page in browser, everything is fine so the problem is not in the html

----update----

I was using Chrome and by clicking the error in the console, the source showed up was the html itself instead of the js file. I tried to specify the full path of the js file in the html, however it still showed me the html file in the error

There js file works fine when I open the html file by enter it dir in the browser

Also in the python console I can see:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2015 00:12:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2015 00:12:28] "GET /full/path/to/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jun/2015 00:12:28] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: it seems that in the file "jquery-1.8.2.min.js" at line 1 there is a "<" which is not valid... are you compressing that file programmatically or is the original one?! Can you provide the full html and the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RequestHandler` will serve up your HTML page regardless of the URL—whether that URL be `/`, `/index.html`, `/favicon.ico`, or (in your case) `/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js`. If you want `/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js` to serve up the actual JavaScript file rather than your HTML page again, you’ll need to handle that specially, e.g.:

```
def do_GET(self):
    if self.path == '/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js':
        filename = 'js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js'
    else:
        filename = 'index.html'
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        self._writeheaders()
        self.wfile.write(f.read())
```

You’ll probably want to change this a little bit such that requesting the JavaScript file gives an appropriate `Content-Type: text/javascript` header rather than `Content-Type: text/html`, and that `HEAD` returns headers consistent with `GET`, etc.

Also, if you ever begin to start serving large files, you may want to consider using [`shutil.copyfileobj`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to copy data from the file to `self.wfile`, rather than reading the whole file into memory and writing it all out.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is there any better way to map the URL request to `do_GET`, such as in Java we use `@RequestMapping('/xxx)` ？

Comment: @pledez: Not with the `BaseHTTPServer` module, no. That said, I’m not sure how involved your project is, but if it’s any more complicated than this it might be worth looking into some libraries that offer that kind of functionality—[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), for example, seems to be a reasonably popular web framework for Python.